# Ttyd and problem with adding a new header using nginx

Tags: rest, nginx, websocket, cors

I have ttyd sharing the terminal window on 8082 port in ec2 aws instance.
I would like to embed the window in a website, but I get CORS problem.
So I would like to add CORS headers to the response from 8082 port.

This is a bash script that I created:

```
nohup su - ubuntu -c 'ttyd -w /home/ubuntu -p 8082 bash' &

sudo systemctl stop nginx

# Configure NGINX for CORS headers with wildcard proxy_pass directive
sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/default > /dev/null << EOL
server {
    listen 8082 default_server;
    listen [::]:8082 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # Use wildcard in proxy_pass directive to proxy pass requests to ttyd server running on port 8082
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        # Add CORS headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
    }
}
EOL

sudo systemctl start nginx
```

With this configuration I get error '500' on 8082 port.
Maybe someone has working nginx configuration for ttyd?